# Clarification on quantification of Categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, pca, dimensionality-reduction, large-data, high-dimensional

I have a countries column with 49 levels. I want to quantify it. If I run CATPCA on  that column would i be able to get the quantified result. Since CatPCA is like PCA or factor analysis: it extracts few "latent" continuous variables out of many original correlating variables

Comment: When you say you want to 'quantify it', do you mean you want to encode a categorical variable as a continuous variable? Are you asking about running CatPCA on a *single* categorical variable and nothing else? What's your goal after you get the continuous values?

Comment: Yes, I want to encode categorical variable as a continuous variable. I want run catpca on each categorical variable individually so that my model can be easily understood as well.